# tExtractJSON table empty Talend

Tags: talend

I have an output that looks like this and I want to get the information with `tExtractJSON` except that it's an empty array that I have.
If anyone has any ideas.

JSON file:

[image]

Configuration:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I finally managed to do it by using Xpath as a reading mode. And I indicated the path of the data. I put "/Items/Fields" as the path

Comment: You could do it by jsonpath, your loop expression was wrong, it should be "$.Items.Fields"